# View visibility not working

Tags: android, visibility, floating-action-button

I'm currently developing an application where
I have a **FAB** that should be **invisible** at activity **start**.

But the fab is visible when just inflating the layout.
Any ideas on how this happens ?

Thank you in advice.

Screenshot taken out of AndroidStudio:
[image]

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/summoner_detail_appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/summoner_detail_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="56dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <kleinschloss.lolticker.ui.widget.RectLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#32000000" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/summoner_detail_icon"
                    android:layout_width="68dp"
                    android:layout_height="68dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
            </kleinschloss.lolticker.ui.widget.RectLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/summoner_detail_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/summoner_detail_tablayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/summoner_detail_fab"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/summoner_detail_appbarlayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/summoner_detail_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the fab `summoner_detail_fab` ? It should be invisible. Are you sure that you are not making this visible again in your Activity code ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the code. I've added a screenshot taken from AndroidStudio.

Comment: try `gone` instead of `invisible`

Comment: Already tried. Believe me I wouldn't ask if I hadn't tried almost everything.

Comment: Could you post the full layout code? I just want to try out in my system.

Comment: This is the full layout code. Didn't even changed view ids or anything.

Comment: What if you set it invisible programmatically? fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: Setting the views visibility in code works fine but I want the view to be invisible at start.

Comment: I see the layout start from here: `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout `. What is the parent of this layout ? That's why i want the full xml.

Comment: For some reason the root layout is not displayed even if its provided with the rest of the code. So I put it here: <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/summoner_detail_coordinator_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into exactly the same issue. It would seem that Google's Android team doesn't want you to have control of the visibility when the FloatingActionButton is anchored to an AppBarLayout, as discussed in this issue - [FloatingActionButton Ignores View Visibility](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175331)

It looks like a viable fix is wrapping the FAB in a CoordinatorLayout and setting the visibility on the wrapper instead, like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/fab_container"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/fab_icon"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You may however wish to consider whether this is the ideal behaviour. Google advocates recommend that the FAB be visible as soon as the screen is created. If you're hiding it for longer than required to animate it in, consider showing a disabled state instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. What a strange decision from Google not letting people control their anchored fabs  visibility.